# Showing Coordinate Lines of a 3D earth

Tags: html, webgl, three.js

Here is a 3D earth made based on `Three js` I want to find the location of Longitude and Latitude of the currently clicked location and show the coordinate lines

What should be the strategy to define those diversion lines?

How could I map my texture to it's correct equivalent Longitude/Latitude?

---

**Edit 1 :**

**My question in a simpler form:**

**How can I get the x, y of the pattern image which was clicked inside the sphere?**

Comment: Check out the params of 'THREE.SphereGeometry()' they allow you to set the origin of an earth like texture. The point of click is available via the intersects array as implemented in this exaymple: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html#L200

Comment: @noiv: You should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Peter, the walk earned no points, why should a walk-through?